# Google Colab V100 GPU Usage

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have two different google drive accounts and I purchased V100 and A100 GPU through google colab (one time purchase) for each account. I can work with V100 GPU in one of my accounts but I cannot on the other.

Why does not Colab let me use V100 GPU on my other account? Is it because there is already one which is busy, working at the moment?